# SVG icon pixel-alignment?

Tags: html, css, svg, antialiasing

[image]

In this image, the left (black) trash can is an icon-font. Its font-size is 16px which causes the icon to look crisp 100% of the time.

The two blue trash cans are SVGs. They have exactly the same markup. One of them *happened* to be pixel-aligned, and the other one wasn't.

How can I force my SVG icons to *always* be pixel-aligned so that they come out sharp, just like font-icons?

Not that I think it's relevant to my question, but the icon in question is [ionicon trash-a.svg](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/v2.0.1/src/trash-a.svg?short_path=ec2afc2). It was designed to look crisp at particular sizes, but I'm pretty sure the browser isn't pixel-aligning it depending on where it lands in a paragraph.

Comment: *"They have the same markup"*. *"One of them happened to be pixel-aligned, and the other one wasn't."* How is this possible ? I think this question will unfortunately turn out to be too broad, because one solution for your markup (that we don't have access to btw) will not work for all markups : If it's a simple global transform issue (like here), you could wrap all elements in a `<g>` then translate it until everything looks fine. But if other paths are positioned on floating coords, then there s no way to make them all fit on rounded coords.

Comment: Ps: if your font-icon is sharp, it's because the author made it pixel-aligned, it has nothing to do with the fact that it's a font-icon. (You can try http://icomoon.io/ and upload your non-pixel-aligned svg, it will be burred just like the svg version)

Comment: @Kaiido Will have to wait til I get home to post you the markup. How is this *not* possible? The SVG path coordinates are identical on both blue trash cans, but the position of the SVG as a whole is different. It's sitting next to some text which will affect its global coordinates. The only the reason the *text* is clear is because of ClearType or whatever which makes sure all the letters are pixel-aligned. Is there not something similar for SVGs?

Comment: @Kaiido In fact, there's a [proposal](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/SVG_hinting#Pixel_snapping) which discusses the issue I'm talking about. I'm pretty sure the black trash can is sharp not *just* because it was designed that way, but also because the browser and/or OS knows how to align *characters*.