# How to cache SVG icons on an external CDN while avoiding FOMI?

Tags: html, css, ajax, performance, svg

I know how to get SVG icons loading on my website, but what I can't figure out is how to satisfy all the following constraints:

1. Ability to use SVG icons in CSS
2. No flash of missing icons (FOMI)
3. Minimal initial page size
4. Cached SVGs
5. Ability to use a CDN
6. Must be able to use `fill: currentColor` to make the icon match the current text color, just like icon-fonts
7. Bonus: [Pixel-align the SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42081449/65387) so they always look sharp

1,2,3 and 4 can be satisfied by using an external sprite map like so:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xlink:href="/assets/sprite-4faa5ef477.svg#icon-asterisk-50af6"></use>
</svg>
```

But we can't use a CDN until browsers fix the [CORS issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470601).

We can [patch in](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse) support for external domains, but I'm pretty sure this won't work for CSS because it only watches the DOM (sorry, haven't tested yet), and also it causes your browser to make a whole bunch of failed requests to a file it can't fetch (one for each icon on the page).

We can use a CDN if instead we either inline the entire SVG (increased page size, no caching) or we AJAX it in (causes FOMI).

So, are there any solutions that satisfy all <del>5</del> 7 constraints?

Basically I want SVGs to be just as convenient as icon-fonts or there's no point switching over. SVGs support multiple colors and are more accessible but I can't get them to look as good, or load as efficiently.

Comment: you could turn your SVGs into an icon font http://fontello.com/

Comment: @HolgerWill Yep. I'm currently using an icon font w/ icomoon, but everyone keeps saying SVGs are all the rage these days, and I'm trying to figure out how exactly they're better. They support multiple colors, sure, but [they don't look as crisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42081449/65387) and they don't work with CDNs, so right now SVGs look like they kind of suck. They're a little bit easier to build with webpack since [FontCustom](https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom/issues/321) seems to be dead.

Comment: i guess something along the lines of what Polymer does... Put your icons in a html file and use html-includes in combination with custom elements, maybe

Answer (score 4):

The closest I could get is loading an SVG in an image element and then using it like an "old-fashioned" [image sprite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS). This, as far as I can tell, satisfies all of your constraints. The only disadvantage I can think of is that you lose the ability to modify specific parts of the SVG using CSS. This is however not one of your constraints (correct me if I'm wrong) and it is still possible to modify all of the icon, as you can see in my demo. I created a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/80q8trt0/1/) and for completeness also include a code snippet.

To emulate a CDN, I created an SVG file and uploaded it to some image hosting service. My apologies to future readers if this service is now down. The SVG file simply has all icons next to each other in it (I created a black square, circle and triangle for now). The difference with SVG sprite maps is thus that the icons are in the SVG itself, not in the [`defs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs). It should be quite easy to combine multiple SVGs in a single one, I have not looked for tools that would automate this process.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30px; /* can be anything */
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url('http://imgh.us/icons_36.svg');
  
  border: 1px solid #000; /* just to see where the icon is */
}

/* sizes */
.icon.large {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 150px auto;
}

/* icons */
.icon.circle { background-position: -30px 0; }
.icon.large.circle { background-position: -50px 0; }
.icon.triangle { background-position: -60px 0; }
.icon.large.triangle { background-position: -100px 0; }

/* styles */
.icon.info {
  /* based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/25524145/962603,
   * but you can of course also use an SVG filter (heh) */
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(50000%) hue-rotate(90deg) brightness(70%);
}
.icon.highlight {
  /* based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/25524145/962603,
   * but you can of course also use an SVG filter (heh) */
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(30deg) brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="icon square"></span>
<span class="icon circle"></span>
<span class="icon triangle"></span>
<span class="icon circle highlight"></span>
<span class="icon triangle large info"></span>
```

Comment: Aww snap. I just kind of assumed I would be able to do `fill: currentColor` and such. That was a secret requirement, but I didn't list it, so I will give you the bounty but I'm going to update the question. Creative thinking!

Comment: That is awesome of you! Thank you very much. I will try to come up with a solution that would allow you to do that. I guess one way would be to do what I suggested and then load everything using AJAX and replace icons when they are loaded? That would be cumbersome though...

Comment: I'm doing something similar to that right now now actually, but I don't like it because the icons change color after the AJAX request completes. I have to do some more experimenting; maybe if I kick off an AJAX request immediately in an `async` script to load the spritemap immediately, then the FOMI won't be so bad.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is to use [data uris](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), which have [pretty great browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). Via something like [Grunticon](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon) or their web app [Grumpicon](http://www.grumpicon.com/).

The output is 2 `css` files and 1 `js` that should work seamlessly with your CDN.

The [rendered output](http://filamentgroup.github.io/grunticon/example/output/preview.html#embedded-svg-option) is very flexible and customizable.

Comment: Data URIs are not cacheable. Might be OK to use in CSS, but I wouldn't want a 1000-byte data URI repeated 200 times in my initial page load HTML.

Comment: Fair enough, hopefully you'll figure something out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem. This probably doesn't satisfy the FOMI requirement, but it's an interesting hack that got me out of a bind. Basically, this script just swaps every img in the DOM that imports an svg with inline SVG, so you can style it how you want.

```
// replaces img tags with svg tags if their source is an svg
// allows SVGs to be manipulated in the DOM directly
//  returns a Promise, so you can execute tasks AFTER fetching SVGs

let fetchSVGs = () => {

//gets all the SRCs of the SVGs
let parentImgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).map((img) => {
    if(img.src.endsWith('.svg')) {
        return img
    }
});

let promises = [];
parentImgs.forEach((img) => {
    promises.push(
        fetch(img.src).then((response) => {
            // Error handling
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                    response.status);
                return;
            }
            // saves the SVG
            return response.text();
        })
    )
});

// All fetch() calls have been made
return Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then((texts)=> {
        texts.forEach((text, i) => {
            let img = parentImgs[i];

            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = text;
            img.parentNode.appendChild(div);
            let svg = div.firstChild;
            img.parentNode.appendChild(svg);

            // makes the SVG inherit the class from its parent
            svg.classList = img.className;

            // removes the junk we don't need.
            div.remove();
            img.parentNode.removeChild(img);

        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
```

Otherwise, I came across this on Twitter today 
https://twitter.com/chriscoyier/status/1124064712067624960
and applying this CSS to a div allowed me to make a colourable svg icon that can be stored in a CDN

```
.icon-mask {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
   -webkit-mask: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-icons/3.0.1/codepen.svg);
   -webkit-mask-size: cover;
}
```

Browser support isn't perfect yet though.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

for cache you can try HTML5 app cache
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: It's been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache